# bash - take string before and after the first delimiter

Tags: bash

I have a field version with value 2022.2.1. I need to get value **2022.2** in all my examples (string before and after the first delimiter).

```
version="2022.2.1"
echo "${version%.*}"
2022.2
```

This works.
But if version contains multiple dots as delimiters (eg. `version="2022.2.1.1"`) it will not work - I need here the value `2022.2`

or even if version contains multiple versions in it it will not work (`version="2022.2.1 2021.1.0"`). Again in this example I need only the first value and it's first string before and after the first delimiter in total.  So always I would like to get value `2022.2`

What is the best practice for this use case?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't easily do this with variable modification. Here, I've used `cut` to pick out the first two `.`-separated fields (see `man cut` for details):

```
for version in '2022.2.1' '2022.2.1.1' '2022.1.1 2021.1.0'
do
    shorter=$(cut -d. -f1-2 <<<"$version")
    printf "version=%s => %s\n" "$version" "$shorter"
done
```

Output

```
version=2022.2.1 => 2022.2
version=2022.2.1.1 => 2022.2
version=2022.1.1 2021.1.0 => 2022.1
```

For POSIX shells without `<<<` you can pipe the string to `cut`

```
shorter=$(printf "%s\n" "$version" | cut -d. -f1-2)
```

Comment: Thank you......

Comment: That assumes `$version` doesn't contain newline characters. Note that `<<<` (from zsh) is just syntactic sugar to shorten here documents. You can do the same with standard here documents.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas newlines - yes quite. I considered using `awk -F. '{print $1 "." $2; exit}'` instead of the `cut` but decided it probably added unnecessary complexity. I find that embedding a standard here doc inside a variable assignment from a command ends up looking messy - and therefore harder to understand at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
$ set -o extendedglob
$ print -r -- ${(M)version##[^.]#.[^.]#}
2022.2
```

`(M)` causes the expansion to result in the `M`atched leading portion instead of stripping the matched portion.

```
$ print -r -- ${(j[.])${(s[.])version}[1,2]}
2022.2
```

(`s`plit on `.` and `j`oin with `.` the first 2 resulting words).

POSIXly:

```
printf '%s\n' "${version%".${version#*.*.}"}"
```

Or:

```
$ LC_ALL=C expr "x$version" : 'x\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)'
2022.2
```

Comment: @glennjackman good point thanks. I've incorporated it.

Answer (score 2):

With plain bash, you can do:

- split and join

  ```bsh
  IFS=. read -ra fields <<< "$version"
  ver2=$(IFS=.; echo "${fields[*]:0:2}")
  ```
- regex capturing

  ```bsh
  [[ $version =~ ([^.]+\.[^.]+) ]] && ver2=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
  ```